# How to translate VB to CSharp using user32.dll?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to translate my VB code to C# code in VS 2017 but seems there are many code doesn't exist in C#.
I am using user32.dll and comctl32.dll in this project.

#My VB.net code.

```
1.   Case No.1    
Private Const WS_POPUP As Integer = &H80000000
Private Const TTF_TRANSPARENT As Short = &H100S
Private Const TTF_CENTERTIP As Short = &H2S

2.  Case No.2
Public Sub ShowToolTip(ByRef OwnerControl As Windows.Forms.Control, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal Title As String = "Information",
    Optional ByVal BackColor As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal IconType As ttIconType = ttIconType.TTIconInfo, Optional ByVal VisibleTime As Integer = 5000)
    Me.TipText = Message
    Me.PopupOnDemand = True
    Me.CreateToolTip(OwnerControl.Handle.ToInt32)
    Me.VisibleTime = VisibleTime
    Me.Title = Title
    Me.Icon = IconType
    If BackColor > 0 Then Me.BackColor = BackColor
    Me.Show(10, OwnerControl.Height - 1, OwnerControl.Handle.ToInt32)
End Sub
```

C# code

```
public void ShowToolTip(System.Windows.Forms.Control OwnerControl, string Message, string Title = "Information", int BackColor = 0, ttIconType IconType = ttIconType.TTIconInfo, int VisibleTime = 5000)
{
    TipText = Message;
    PopupOnDemand = true;
    this.CreateToolTip(OwnerControl.Handle.ToInt32);
    this.VisibleTime = VisibleTime;
    this.Title = Title;
    Icon = IconType;
    if (BackColor > 0)
        this.BackColor = BackColor;
    //int argX = 10;
    //var argY = OwnerControl.Height - 1;        
    this.Show(10, OwnerControl.Height, OwnerControl.Handle.ToInt32);
}
```

Actually, it doesn't exist with this line of code

```
 OwnerControl.Handle.ToInt32
```

Of course, I am not much understanding about using "user32.dll" and "comctl32.dll".

Could someone help me to translate this into C#?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the error?  What is `OwnerControl.Handle.ToInt32`?  Generally you don't want to directly convert from one language to another line-by-line.  The results will either be something that doesn't work, or something that kind of works but you don't understand how or why and is terrible code.  Instead, implement the functionality you want in the target language.  What functionality are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ToInt32() is a function, so add parentheses like in this comment.

Comment: Thank you very much to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IntPtr.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.toint32?view=netframework-4.8) is a method, not a property.  And in C# method calls must use paranetheses, which are optional in VB.

So

```
OwnerControl.Handle.ToInt32()
```

And

Short is Int16
Integer is Int32

but these look like PInvoke values, so the signs don't really matter, and they should probably all be unsigned.  eg

```
private const UInt32 WS_POPUP = 0x80000000;
private const UInt16 TTF_TRANSPARENT = 0x00;
private const UInt16 TTF_CENTERTIP = 0x2;
```

Comment: Thank you @David Browne, it is such a small thing that I over looking. It is very useful